# Laptop powerbank, AC current

Tags: batteries, ac, ac-dc

I want to buy a laptop powerbank which output AC current, in which I then plug the stock charger of my laptop.

It it a good idea, or I should rather buy a powerbank that directly output 12v so I can directly plug it in the laptop? Is there a big efficiency difference, or a preferred option?

Comment: Using the power bank directly is definitely more efficient. Also are your sure your laptop accepts 12V?

Comment: If you really want 120VAC output, your best bet is the [Anker PowerHouse](https://www.anker.com/deals/powerhouse2). Otherwise, a power bank that directly outputs your laptop's DC voltage is ideal.

Comment: a cheap 5v to 12-18v step up will allow a USB bank to charge your laptop. slowly.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is like a UPS. Computer UPS'es are optimized for a few minutes runtime at high power, which doesn't fit your needs. A battery and an inverter would be better.

However, this is not an efficient solution, as the energy stored in the battery will go through a DC-AC conversion in the UPS, then another AC-DC conversion in the laptop's power brick.

I'll use 85% efficiency for the [power brick](https://us.hardware.info/reviews/3151/12/round-up-of-74-laptop-power-adapters-original-or-universal-test-results), although it will vary with load and adapter.

Inverter efficiency is more complicated. Oldskool transformer-based ones will have terrible efficiency (like 50%) at low loads (say, a 60W laptop on a 500VA UPS). More modern ones will fare a lot better, like 90%. If your laptop draws 100W max, pick a 200VA inverter, not a 1kVA one, to make sure it doesn't run outside of its best efficiency range.

So you can expect a global efficiency of around 75% if the inverter is good. This means 25% of battery energy will be wasted, so you'll need a larger battery.

If you power your 12V inverter from a lithium 12V battery pack which has an internal DC-DC to output a constant 12V, then this converter will also have losses. In this case you have 3 converters in series... quite the kludge.

Simpler solutions would be:

- Car laptop adapter powered by 12V battery.
- 6S Lithium pack with a 19V buck converter (if your laptop uses 19V).
- 12V battery connected to laptop, if laptop accepts 12V.

Comment: OP is asking about battery plus inverter while you are targeting UPS. At least you should have used the long lasting type of UPS rather than the more common high power short time ones.

Comment: Right, I edited my answer.